# How to determine collision in python in right way

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

Here I have made a code to create random sized bubbles which can be destroyed by collision of another object:

```
import tkinter
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("...")
c = tkinter.Canvas(width=800, height=500, bg="...")
ojct_id1 = c.create_polygon(...)
ojct_id2 = c.create_oval(...)           # A polygon in an oval should constitute the object
def move ojct(event):
    ...
from random import randint
bubbles = list()
bubbles_r = list()                    # radius
bubbles_speed = list()
def create_bub():
    ...
def move_bubbles():
    ...
from time import sleep
while True:
    if randint(1, 10) == 1:
        create_bub()
    move_bubbles()
    window.update()
    sleep(0.01)
```

The following code determines the position of any bubble:That helps to find out collision.

```
def hole_coord(id_num):
    pos = c.coords(id_num)
    x = (pos[0] + pos[2])/2
    y = (pos[1] + pos[3])/2
    return x, y
```

Now I have to make func. for deleting bubbles:

```
def del_bubbles():
    del bubbles_r[i]
    del bubbles_speed[i]
    c.delete(bubbles[i])
    del bubbles[i]
```

The following code determines, if the two objects are colliding:

```
from math import sqrt
def distance(id1, id2):
    x1, y1 = hole_coord(id1)
    x2, y2 = hole_coord(id2)
    return sqrt((x2 - x1)/2 + (y2 - y1)/2)
def collision():
    for bub in range(len(bubbles)-1, -1, -1):
        if distance(ojct_id2, bubbles[bub]) < (15 + bubbles_r[bub]):
            del_bubbles(bub)
```

Here it is sth. wrong: bubbles get deleted without a hit but if they are hit 
often they don't get deleted. Can anybody help me? Thanks!

Comment: I think your distance function is wrong, it should be `return sqrt((x1-x2)**2+(y1-y2)**2)`

Comment: Thank you pLOPeGG!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not computing the euclidean distance correctly.

```
def distance(id1, id2):
    x1, y1 = hole_coord(id1)
    x2, y2 = hole_coord(id2)
    return sqrt((x2 - x1)/2 + (y2 - y1)/2)   # <----- this is wrong
```

should be

```
def distance(id1, id2):
    x1, y1 = hole_coord(id1)
    x2, y2 = hole_coord(id2)
    return sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)   # <----- square instead of halve
```

Comment: Well, thank you kutschkem, I'm bad at math, you know :-D

Comment: @Timmy Don't believe that. ;-)